# How to allocate seperate memory to store confidential data?

Tags: c++, linux

I would like to know, if it is possible to allocate a separate memory area in some library, such that an application using said library cannot access it directly.

Lets say this library exposes a class, that needs confidential data in order to operate. For example the following class, where an instance of this class contains a confidential access token, that would allow a malicious user to be able to access a database without the need to login.

```
class Session {
public:
  Session(const Database *database, const std::string& name) : username(name), login_expires(-1), db(database) {}
  virtual ~Session(){}

  bool renew_login(const std::string& password);
private:
  const Database* db;
  long login_exiration_date;

  // confidential data:
  std::string username;      
  char confidental_accesstoken[128];
};
```

When I have a Session instance named s, where a user is currently logged in, I would be able to extract the accesstoken simply by casting a &s to a character pointer.

Now I would like to reimplement this class to the following class:

```
class Session {
public:
  Session(const Database *database, const std::string& name) : username(name), login_expires(-1), db(database) {}
  virtual ~Session(){}

  bool renew_login(const std::string& password);
private:
  const Database* db;
  long login_exiration_date;

  long some_temporary_id;
};
```

If the class Session is declared like this, it is no longer possible for an end application to access the confidential data, as it is no longer stored inside the session instance itself.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have to store the confidential data in such a way, that it can not be accessed in the end application simply by using pointer arithmetic.

I know, that I cannot protect the data in such a way that a root user cannot dump all memory to disk and search it, but that is not my goal I want to accomplish.

I want to have a private memory space inside my library, such that a normal userspace application with ordinary access rights, has to use my interface in order to work with these restricted resources.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need a separate process to hold the data. By definition any code running in the same process sees the same address space.

Comment: Use a separate process and in it you can optionally `mlock` your secure memory to prevent it from getting swapped to disk. That's what security software like gnupg does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have any chance of storing Data in a way that it cannot be accessed by other functions in the same process. You can make it harder by storing the data in some file/thread_local variable, but again, that will only hide the data, not protect it.